# SugarCRM soap call not linking contact to a target list

Tags: soap, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM 6.4.4 and php 5.3.10 and trying to add a contact to a target list using a soap call...I've also tried using the ProspectList class directly but I can't get it to work.  I know the SOAP calls are getting through because I can create the Contact just fine, but the problem is coming when I try to create the relationship between the Contact and the Target List (PropsectList).  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the SOAP call I tried.  I'm getting an error that says: "Call to a member function add() on a non-object in /data/servers/thesite.com/web/administrator/sales/soap/SoapSugarUsers.php on line 1350"...Here's the code around line 1350

```
if (!empty($key)) {
    $mod->load_relationship($key);
    $mod->$key->add($module2_id);
    return $error->get_soap_array();
}
```

Here's the full code for the SOAP:

```
// set up options array
$options = array(
        "location" => 'http://www.thesite.com/sales/soap.php',
        "uri" => 'http://www.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm',
        "trace" => 1
        );

//user authentication array
$user_auth = array(
"user_name" => 'theuser',
"password" => MD5('thepass'),
"version" => '.01'
);

// connect to soap server
$client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);

// Login to SugarCRM
$response = $client->login($user_auth,'test');

$session_id = $response->id;

$user_id = $client->get_user_id($session_id);


//Add Contact to SugarCRM
$response = $client->set_entry($session_id, 'Contacts', array(
array('name' => 'first_name','value' => 'roneFirst2'),
array('name' => 'last_name','value' => 'roneLast2'),
array('name' => 'account_name','value' => 'jdam Props'),
array('name' => 'email1','value' => 'roneEmail2@gmail.com'),
array('name' => 'work_phone','value' => '1.888.888.8888'),
array('name' => 'description','value' => 'This is the message'),
array('name' => 'assigned_user_id','value' => $user_id)
));
$contact_id = $response->id;


//Add Contact to TARGET LIST
$relationship = array(
'module1' => 'Contacts',
'module1_id' => "$contact_id",
'module2' => 'ProspectLists',
'module2_id' => "24053784-f8d3-22a4-5e99-4fc6a7d5159f"  //Note: this id was pulled from the table in the database directly for the target list we want to link the contact with.
);

//call set_relationship()
$response = $client->set_relationship($session_id, $relationship);
```

been googleing and trying to figure this out for 3 days now...Thanks for any help you are willing to give.